# MAXIMA string to integer conversion

Tags: string, maxima

I am reading a list with 2 integers from a file using readline(s) which returns a string. How does one convert the string of 2 integers back to 2 integers? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a string like "123 456". If so you can do this: `map(parse_string, split(s))` where `s` is your string.

`parse_string` parses one Maxima expression, e.g. one integer. To get both integers, split the string, which makes a list, and then parse each element of the list.